# Problems during binding SpotLight to the instance

Tags: windows-7, spotlight, oracle-11g

I have RAC Oracle11 installation built from 2 nodes running on Linux Red Hat OS.

Now, I try to make connection from SpotLight running on Windows 7 to the Instance of one of nodes (TNS name of it is: LIBD1)

This what I do:

Make new connection -> give user with SYS permission -> connect -> get error about that, that user not configured -> User Configuration Wizard opens -> give SYS as user with sysdba permissions (real SYS not other user with SYS permission) -> check "configure new user" option -> give new user name -> next

And I get error: DBMS_SQL access.denied.

What I do wrong?
Thank you for ahead.

Comment: This the full error in Spotlight:

An error has occured in table DropSysSyn in connection LIBD1 with the following error
ORA-29471: DBMS_SQL access denied
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1017
ORA-06512: at line 8 in table DropSYSSyn

Comment: And this is relevant lines from trace file: DBMS_SQL Security error: ORA-29471!
0x4cf622608 1046 package body SYS.DBMS_SQL
0x4ff284580 16 anonymous block